# how to split string into variable and array

Tags: java

i need to read a text file that has a of string
for instance 
aerosmith toys_in_the_attic Toys_In_The_Attic Uncle_Salty Adam's_Apple Walk_This_Way Big_Ten_Inch_Record Sweet_Emotion No_More_No_More Round_And_Round You_See_Me_Crying

i need to split this into artist(aerosmith) album(toy_in_the_attic) and all the songs only(Toys_In_The_Attic Uncle_Salty Adam's_Apple Walk_This_Way Big_Ten_Inch_Record Sweet_Emotion No_More_No_More Round_And_Round You_See_Me_Crying) into an array list

this is the code i have

```
   File aFile = new File("catalog2.txt");
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(aFile);

    catalog = new ArrayList<Album>();

    while (inFile.hasNextLine())
    {
        String line = inFile.nextLine();
        String[] details = line.split(" ");
         String artistName = details[0];
        String albumName = details[1];
        albumTracks.add(details[2]);
        Album myAlbums = new Album(artistName, albumName, albumTracks);
        catalog.add(myAlbums);
    }
    inFile.close();
```

what happens is the out looks like this

```
artistName = aerosmith albumName = toys_in_the_attic tracks = [Toys_In_The_Attic]

artistName = aerosmith albumName = permanent_vacation tracks = [Toys_In_The_Attic, Heart's_Done_Time]

artistName = aerosmith albumName = pump tracks = [Toys_In_The_Attic, Heart's_Done_Time, Young_Lust]
```

each line should have its own list of songs not repeat and add 
any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be a better practice to declare a new Scanner that iterates in lines.

Here is how I would do it :

```
List<Album> albums = new ArrayList<Album>();
String artistName = "", albumName = "";
ArrayList<String> albumTracks;

while (inFile.hasNextLine()) {
    Scanner inLine = new Scanner(inFile.nextLine());
    if(inLine.hasNext()) artistName = inLine.next();
    if(inLine.hasNext()) albumName = inLine.next();
    albumTracks = new ArrayList<>();

    while (inLine.hasNext()) {
        albumTracks.add(inLine.next());
    }

    albums.add(new Album(artistName, albumName, albumTracks));
}
```

Comment: i've tried this and it only ready the first line of the text file

Comment: tried it myself and it worked, did you declare inFile like in your post ? send me your code from pastebin or something like that

Comment: this issue with this code and mine is it wont let me covert the List<string> into an arrayLists. albumTracks is an arraylist in the constructor

Comment: seems like its working only thing is the output is one line instead of album name, artist and songs for each album object on a different line

Comment: maybe I misunderstood your project, is it <artist> <albumname> <songs> on each line ? and aerosmith is the first string of each line ?

Comment: there are 78 line in the text file each line starts off with a different artitst. the album the artist and songs should be but in an arraylist of album and then when you display it say using a loop there should be the album name/ artist name/ and the songs associated with the album

Comment: oh, indeed i misunderstood your question. Please try this code (I updated my answer), and keep my in touch.

Answer (score 0):

First just remove all extra spaces from your input text for using `line.split(" ");`

```
while (inFile.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = inFile.nextLine();
        line = line.replace(" = ", "=")
                .replace("= ", "=")
                .replace(" =", "=")
                .replace(", ", ",")
                .replace(" , ", ",")
                .replace(" ,", ",");

        String[] details = line.split(" ");
        String artistName = details[0].split("=")[1];
        String albumName = details[1].split("=")[1];
        String tracks = details[2].split("=")[1];
        Album myAlbums =
                new Album(
                        artistName,
                        albumName,
                        tracks.substring(1, tracks.length() - 1).split(",")
                );
        catalog.add(myAlbums);
    }
```

Album Class:

```
   class Album {

    private final String   artistName;
    private final String   albumName;
    private final String[] albumTracks;

    public Album(String artistName, String albumName, String[] albumTracks) {
        this.artistName = artistName;
        this.albumName = artistName;
        this.albumTracks = albumTracks;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know if albumTracks in Album is a List so I am assuming it is as per your question and below is what you can try. You need to import java.util.Arrays

I am also assuming here that your data has at least 3 words else you need to put null and size checks.

```
File aFile = new File("catalog2.txt");
Scanner inFile = new Scanner(aFile);

catalog = new ArrayList<Album>();

while (inFile.hasNextLine())
{
    String line = inFile.nextLine();
    String[] details = line.split(" ");
    String artistName = details[0];
    String albumName = details[1];
    // find location of 3rd word and create list of albums from there
    List<String> albumTracks = Arrays.asList(line.substring(line.indexOf(details[1]) + details[1].length() + 1).split(“ “));
    Album myAlbums = new Album(artistName, albumName, albumTracks);
    catalog.add(myAlbums);
}
inFile.close();
```

Answer (score -1):

You declared arraylist outside of the while loop. That results in the ArrayList that adds all songs the scanner reads.
The code should be:

```
    File aFile = new File("catalog2.txt");
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(aFile);

    catalog = new ArrayList<Album>();

    while (inFile.hasNextLine()) {

        //Declare inside the loop
        ArrayList<String> albumTracks = new ArrayList<String>();
        /**********************/
        String line = inFile.nextLine();
        String[] details = line.split(" ");
        String artistName = details[0];
        String albumName = details[1];
        albumTracks.add(details[2]);
        Album myAlbums = new Album(artistName, albumName, albumTracks);
        catalog.add(myAlbums);
    }
    inFile.close();
```

Comment: i tried this one and it will only add the first son of the album output looks likertistName = 98_degrees albumName = 98_degrees_and_rising tracks = [Intro]
artistName = beatles albumName = A_Hard_Day's_Night tracks = [A_Hard_Day's_Night]
artistName = avalon albumName = a_maze_of_grace tracks = [Testify_To_Love]
artistName = beatles albumName = abbey_road tracks = [Come_Together]
artistName = u2 albumName = achtung_baby tracks = [Zoo_Station] there is more than one song in each album